# SFTP with Google Cloud Composer

Tags: sftp, google-cloud-composer

I need to upload a file via SFTP into an external server through Cloud Composer. The code for the task is as follows:

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator
    from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
    
    def make_sftp():
        import paramiko
        import pysftp
        import os
        from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
        import subprocess
    
    
        ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="conn_id")
        sftp_client = ssh_hook.get_conn().open_sftp()
    
        return 0
    
    
    etl_dag = DAG("dag_test",
                  start_date=datetime.now(tz=local_tz),
                  schedule_interval=None,
                  default_args={
                      "owner": "airflow",
                      "depends_on_past": False,
                      "email_on_failure": False,
                      "email_on_retry": False,
                      "retries": 5,
                      "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)})
    
    sftp = PythonVirtualenvOperator(task_id="sftp",
                                    python_callable=make_sftp,
                                    requirements=["sshtunnel", "paramiko"],
    
                                    dag=etl_dag)
    
    start_pipeline = DummyOperator(task_id="start_pipeline", dag=etl_dag)
    
    start_pipeline >> sftp
```

In "conn_id" I have used the following options: {"no_host_key_check": "true"}, the DAG runs for a couple of seconds and the fail with the following message:

```
WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks\n[2022-02-10 10:01:59,358] {ssh_hook.py:171} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/venvur4zvddz/script.py", line 23, in <module>\n    res = make_sftp(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/tmp/venvur4zvddz/script.py", line 19, in make_sftp\n    sftp_client = ssh_hook.get_conn().open_sftp()\n  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 194, in get_conn\n    client.connect(**connect_kwargs)\n  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 412, in connect\n    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()\n  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 834, in get_remote_server_key\n    raise SSHException("No existing session")\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session\n'
```

do I have to set other options? Thank you!

Comment: Can you also include the Keyfile Path in Conn Id and try? Please let me know if this resolves your issue or not.

Comment: Do you mean the path to the private/public key? I am not sure when I should generate it, should I generate it on the fly every time the DAG runs?

Comment: Hi @steu, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT, no I still have the same issue (paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session), is it possible to authenticate just with username and password? Without keys being involved. I am using "no_host_key_check": "true", but it seems it is still looking for keys. Thanks

Comment: It’s not possible to connect to SFTP only using username and password. As mentioned in this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/connections/sftp.html#authenticating-to-sftp), there are two ways to connect to SFTP using Airflow. One way is to connect using the host key and another way is using key_file. You still need to provide a path to your private/public SSH Key as follows in extras `{"key_file": "key_file_path", "no_host_key_check": true}`.

Comment: Same problem (get_remote_server_key\n    raise SSHException("No existing session")\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session\n') I try to add my private key and set `{"key_path":".ssh/id_rsa", "no_host_key_check": "true", "allow_host_key_change":"true", "allow_agent"="false","look_for_keys"="false"}`

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of Airflow you are using?

Comment: Airflow is 1.10.15 and Composer is 1.17.2

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using to run the DAG?

Comment: I have added the full code above.

Comment: When specifying the private key path, the key file should be accessible from the Composer/Airflow environment. To make the key file accessible, it has to be uploaded to the GCS bucket associated with the Composer environment. For example: The `Extra` JSON dictionary would look like this.  `{"key_file": "/home/airflow/gcs/data/sftp-ssh-key", "conn_timeout": "10", "no_host_key_check": "true"}`. Here, I have uploaded the key file to the `data` folder in the Composer environment's GCS bucket. Can you make this change and let me know if it resolves your issue?

Comment: If my answer addressed you question consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, do let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the other community members with their researches as well :)

Comment: Thanks @KabilanMohanraj, your answer helped a lot. Unfortunately it seems that I don't have permission to copy the public key into the server (it's an external server that I don't control). Is there a way to force login just with login and password? I see in the doc (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/connections/sftp.html#authenticating-to-sftp) that it has the options for username and pw.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my answer with information on password authentication. Do let me know if the solution helps!

Comment: I have already tried that approach but it gives the same error as above. I'm wondering if there are any restictions by the remote server on requests coming from GCP.

Comment: Is password authentication configured on the host machine? Have there been any successful results before?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to launch the code locally using pysftp and it works, but when I laubch it from cloud I get socket timeout. Probably it's the host machine that is not accepting connections coming from GCP.

Comment: The people who handle the server told me that probably it's a VPC issue and somehow I cannot get out of the VPC network.

Comment: Hello. You can try to increase the connection timeout for the request. You can also check the firewall rules to see if they allow outbound (egress) `ssh` connections. Also, can you please create a new question for the timeout issue? With a new question, the community will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Configuring the SSH connection with key pair authentication

To SSH into the host as a user with username “user_a”, an SSH key pair should be generated for that user and the public key should be added to the host machine. The following are the steps that would create an SSH connection to the “jupyter” user which has the write permissions.

1. Run the following commands on the local machine to generate the required SSH key:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/sftp-ssh-key -C user_a
```

“sftp-ssh-key” → Name of the pair of public and private keys (Public key: sftp-ssh-key.pub, Private key: sftp-ssh-key)

“user_a” → User in the VM that we are trying to connect to

```sh
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/sftp-ssh-key
```

2. Now, copy the contents of the public key `sftp-ssh-key.pub` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of your host system. Check for necessary permissions for `authorized_keys` and grant them accordingly using `chmod`.

   I tested the setup with a Compute Engine VM . In the Compute Engine console, edit the VM settings to add the contents of the generated SSH public key into the instance metadata. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata). If you are connecting to a Compute Engine VM, make sure that the instance has the [appropriate firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow the SSH connection.
3. Upload the private key to the client machine. In this scenario, the client is the Airflow DAG so the key file should be accessible from the Composer/Airflow environment. To make the key file accessible, it has to be uploaded to the GCS bucket associated with the Composer environment. For example, if the private key is uploaded to the `data` folder in the bucket, the key file path would be `/home/airflow/gcs/data/sftp-ssh-key`.

---

### Configuring the SSH connection with password authentication

If password authentication is not configured on the host machine, follow the below steps to **enable password authentication**.

1. Set the user password using the below command and enter the new password twice.

```
sudo passwd user_a
```

2. To enable SSH password authentication, you must SSH into the host machine as root to edit the `sshd_config` file.

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

3. Then, change the line **`PasswordAuthentication no`** to **`PasswordAuthentication yes`**. After making that change, restart the SSH service by running the following command as root.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Password authentication has been configured now.

---

### Creating connections and uploading the DAG

#### 1.1 Airflow connection with key authentication

Create a connection in Airflow with the below configuration or use the existing connection.

[image]

##### Extra field

The Extra JSON dictionary would look like this. Here, we have uploaded the private key file to the `data` folder in the Composer environment's GCS bucket.

```py
{
   "key_file": "/home/airflow/gcs/data/sftp-ssh-key",
   "conn_timeout": "30",
   "look_for_keys": "false"
}
```

#### 1.2 Airflow connection with password authentication

If the host machine is configured to allow password authentication, these are the changes to be made in the Airflow connection.
The `Extra` parameter can be empty.

[image]

The `Password` parameter is the user_a's user password on the host machine.

The task logs show that the password authentication was successful.

```
INFO - Authentication (password) successful!
```

2. Upload the DAG to the Composer environment and trigger the DAG. I was facing key validation issue with the latest version of the `paramiko=2.9.2` library. I tried downgrading `paramiko` but the older versions do not seem to support OPENSSH keys. Found an alternative [`paramiko-ng`](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko-ng/) in which the validation issue has been fixed. Changed the Python dependency from `paramiko` to `paramiko-ng` in the `PythonVirtualenvOperator`.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def make_sftp():
    import paramiko
    from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook

    ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="sftp_connection")
    sftp_client = ssh_hook.get_conn().open_sftp()
    
    print("=================SFTP Connection Successful=================")
    
    remote_host = "/home/sftp-folder/sample_sftp_file" # file path in the host system
    local_host = "/home/airflow/gcs/data/sample_sftp_file" # file path in the client system
    
    sftp_client.get(remote_host,local_host) # GET operation to copy file from host to client
    
    sftp_client.close()
    return 0


etl_dag = DAG("sftp_dag",
                start_date=datetime.now(),
                schedule_interval=None,
                default_args={
                    "owner": "airflow",
                    "depends_on_past": False,
                    "email_on_failure": False,
                    "email_on_retry": False,
                    "retries": 5,
                    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)})

sftp = PythonVirtualenvOperator(task_id="sftp",
                                python_callable=make_sftp,
                                requirements=["sshtunnel", "paramiko-ng", "pysftp"],
                                dag=etl_dag)

start_pipeline = DummyOperator(task_id="start_pipeline", dag=etl_dag)

start_pipeline >> sftp
```

---

### Results

The `sample_sftp_file` has been copied from the host system to the specified Composer bucket.

[image]

Comment: wondering why you did not picked up the 'SFTP' Conn Type?