# How to transfer files and directories from remote server to GCS buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm stucked. I have to import files and directories from remote server (proably Linux) to GCS buckets with a given scheduling time (let's say weekly). 
There are several folders on the server, one for each project. Inside the project folder there are other folders that have the name of dates (20221015, 20221019, ...). Inside each of these folders there are other subfolders. 
I have to migrate an entire folder starting from the date-folder, every week.\

1. First question: which Google Service is better for my purpose: `Storage Transfer Service` or `Cloud Composer` (is there an Operator for this task)?
2. Second question: how can I avoid to import date-folders that I have already imported (i.e. one week ago)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Create a bash script and a cron entry on your VM. It shouldn't be too complex to write I think. Forget Storage Transfer Service and Composer

Comment: Linux server is not controlled by me. It's a thirdy party server. This is why I need to attach a connector from GCP

Comment: So, you want Cloud Storage push the file to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cloud Composer, you may use [SFTPToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/sftp_to_gcs/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sftp_to_gcs).

Here is a working DAG on my end:

```py
import os

from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sftp_to_gcs import SFTPToGCSOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {"start_date": days_ago(1)}

DIR_path = "<your-path>"
BUCKET_SRC = "<your-bucket>"

with models.DAG(
    "dag_sftp_to_gcs", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None
) as dag:

    copy_sftp_to_gcs = SFTPToGCSOperator(
        task_id="t_sftp_to_gcs",
        sftp_conn_id="<your-connection>",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        source_path=os.path.join(DIR_path, "*.xlsx"), #you may use wildcard to get multiple files
        destination_bucket=BUCKET_SRC,
    )

    copy_sftp_to_gcs
```

Remember though that you need to allow ssh in your firewall settings. You may also follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063147/sftp-with-google-cloud-composer) on how to create connections in Airflow.

File in my VM:

[image]

Status in Airflow Console:

[image]

Transferred file in GCS:

[image]

For your second question, you may create an internal shell script on your server that transfers/deletes file that you want to retain or remove so that correct files will be fetched by Airflow.