# Copy file from windows remote server to GCS bucket using Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, remote-server, google-cloud-storage

file_path = "\\wfs8-XXXXX\XXXX"

The files is on remote server path, I am using cloud composer to automate my data pipeline,

so How I will be able to copy the files from remote windows server to GCS bucket using composer ?

I tried to use LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator, but I am not able to provide any connection option to connect windows remote server, please advise

```
upload_file = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
        task_id="upload_file",
        src=PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE,
        dst=DESTINATION_FILE_LOCATION,
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use [SFTPToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/sftp_to_gcs.html) operator, example :

```py
copy_file_from_sftp_to_gcs = SFTPToGCSOperator(
    task_id="file-copy-sftp-to-gcs",
    sftp_conn_id="<your-connection>",
    source_path=f"{FILE_LOCAL_PATH}/{OBJECT_SRC_1}",
    destination_bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
)
```

You have to configure the sftp connection in `Airflow`, you can check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71211693/9261558) to have an example.